# Implode PHP array and display text strings in their own DIVs

Tags: php, html, mysql, joomla

I am using the following database query and PHP code to retrieve checkbox values and display them on the page as HTML.

```
$submissionId = JRequest::getInt('submissionId'); 

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `FormId`, `FieldName`, `FieldValue` FROM `#__rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FormId` = '5' AND `SubmissionId` = '$submissionId' AND `FieldName` = 'documents'");
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $documentsArray[] = $row->FieldValue;
}

$document = implode(' ', $documentsArray);

$formLayout .= '<div class="formContainer">';
$formLayout .= '<div class="formView">';

for($i = 0; $i < count($document); $i++) {
    $formLayout .= "<div>" . $document . "</div>";
}

$formLayout .= '</div>';
$formLayout .= '</div>';
```

The code is partially working. The problem lies in the "FieldValue" row containing one or more checkbox values. I am needing to have each checkbox value formatted and displayed in it's own DIV like I have detailed below.

```
<div>Checkbox value #1</div>
<div>Checkbox value #2</div>
<div>Checkbox value #3</div>
```

I only need to show the checkbox values and not the checkboxes themselves. Any tips on how I can select each individual string from the imploded array and display it in it's own DIV. Thank you.

Comment: Could you print out $documentsArray in a print_r()?

Comment: @NicholasYoung This is what is displayed using print_r() `Array(
    [0] => 
        Most Recent Financial Statement
        Management Agreement
        Bylaws
        Insurance Policy
        Most Recent Board of Directors Minutes
)`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove a little part of your code:

```
$submissionId = JRequest::getInt('submissionId'); 

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT `FormId`, `FieldName`, `FieldValue` FROM `#__rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FormId` = '5' AND `SubmissionId` = '$submissionId' AND `FieldName` = 'documents'");
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

$formLayout .= '<div class="formContainer">';
$formLayout .= '<div class="formView">';

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $formLayout .= "<div>" . $row->FieldValue . "</div>";
}

$formLayout .= '</div>';
$formLayout .= '</div>';
```

Or implode in "divs":

```
...
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $documentsArray[] = $row->FieldValue;
}

$document = implode('</div><div>', $documentsArray);

$formLayout .= '<div class="formContainer">';
$formLayout .= '<div class="formView">';
$formLayout .= '<div>' . $document . '</div>';
$formLayout .= '</div>';
$formLayout .= '</div>';
```

Comment: @MikeHermary It is not possible, the code I've posted is all right, unless the value of `$row->Field Value` is more than one value. Look at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e7192b5da3a108381b60aca55593534cbf6fea1 for a example of second model.